# How to identify which option selected on UIActivityViewController before presenting respective view modally?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a button on my view, on click of which I am presenting user with UIactivityViewController, to select options from Message and Mail.
Now I want to know how to identify which option was selected by user, so that I can perform custom check and modifications to navigation and status bar when presenting mfmailcomposeviewcontroller modally?
Also, I want to implement other checks whether device is capable of sending emails or not, this can be done only if I am able to determine, if user selected Mail option from UIActivityViewController.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do this with the default built-in activities. All you get is the `completionHandler` which only gets called once the action is cancelled or completed. If you want more granular control you can create your own activity and implement it yourself.

The built-in share options are also disabled automatically if they are not usable. If you need to, you can perform extra checks and if you want to disable a particular activity, use the `excludedActivityTypes` property of your `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: Is there any way, I can set tint color and status bar style when these views are presented modally? the typical setTintColor is not working for me here.